# Implementing t-SNE (t-Distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embedding)

Tags: programming, visualization, machine-learning, algorithm

## Context

Six months ago [@M.R.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/403/m-r) asked about an implementation of the [t-Distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embedding](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/publications/papers/JMLR_2008.pdf) (t-SNE) algorithm by van der Maaten and Hinton (2008). ([@M.R.'s question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121711/t-sne-visualization))

[@Alexey Golyshev](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/23402/alexey-golyshev) gave a solid answer utilizing `RLink`. However, I thought it would be more interesting* to try and implement t-SNE in Mathematica (v11+). However I have run into a bit of difficulty and would appreciate the community's help.

*it may also have a minimal relation to MacOS related [issues with `RLink`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137960/rlink-error-with-dynamic-libraries-on-mac-10-12-with-mathematica-v11).

**Note**: I like to code using Mathematica's symbolic notation (and hence it looks like crude even with the Mathematica Stack Exchange Plugin). A notebook with the code can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/Wolfram-tSNE) (rather than a mess of a
`\[VariousLongSymbolNames]` for a post).

## Pseudo-Code

Page 2587 gives a the pseudo-code for the t-SNE algorithm:

---

**Algorithm 1**

**Data**: data set $\chi=\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}$,
cost function parameters: perplexity *Perp*,
optimization parameters: number of iterations $T$, learning rate $\eta$, momentum $\alpha(t)$.
**Result**: low-dimensional data representation $Y^{(T)}=\{y_1, y_2, \dotsm  y_n\}.$

**begin**
----compute pariwase affinities $p_{j|i}$ with perplexity *Perp* (using Equation 1)
----set $p_{ij}=\frac{p_{j|i}+p_{i|j}}{2n}$ 
----sample initial solution $Y^{(0)}=\{y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n\}$ from $N(0,10^{-4}I)$
----**for** $t=1$ **to** $T$ **do**
--------computer low-dimensional affinities $q_{ij}$ (using Equation 4)
--------compute gradient $\frac{\delta C}{\delta Y}$ (using Equation 5)
--------set $Y^{(t)}=Y^{(t-1)}+\eta \frac{\delta C}{\delta Y} + \alpha(t)(Y^{(t-1)}-Y^{(t-2)})$
----**end**
**end**

---

## Equations

**1**
$$
p_{j\vert i}=\frac{\exp(-\| x_i-x_j\|^2/2\sigma^2)}{\sum_{k\neq i}\exp(-\| x_i-x_k\|^2/2\sigma^2)}
$$

**4**
$$
q_{ij}=\frac{(1+\| y_i-y_j\|^2)^{-1}}{\sum_{k\neq l}(1+\| y_i-y_l\|^2)^{-1}}
$$

**5**
$$
\frac{\delta C}{\delta y_i}=4\sum_j(p_{ij}-q_{ij})(y_i-y_j)(1+\| y_i-y_j\|^2)^{-1}
$$

## Implementation

So here is what I have been able to implement so far... (see [code](https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/Wolfram-tSNE))

## Questions

- how to better handle functions requiring access to elements of the `Dataset`. I like assigning $x_i$ values inside `Table` (which does work), however I fear that this is against convention?
- how can I write this following Mathematica conventions?
- how to update the learning term?
- any obvious mistakes?

## Git

[code](https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/Wolfram-tSNE)

## Update

One may notice that the pseudo-code from the original paper has a typo. It has a recurrence relation for the gradient, which depends on the previous two gradients; only one gradient is initialized, however. Ergo one needs to define $T^{-1}$ to be something (perhaps) all zeros.

In addition, as pointed out in the comments, although variance is continually referred to as $\sigma_i$ in the paper, that is a repeated typo and should be $\sigma^2_i$.

Comment: `I` is an `IdentityMatrix`. Also you don't need to square `Variance` and there exists `SquaredEuclideanDistance`.

Comment: @swish how come? That is the formula provided...

Comment: `Variance` is already a $\sigma^2$ afaik

Comment: @SumNeuron You can take the Python code [here](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/) and make the naive translation of it to the Wolfram language + `Compile`.

Comment: @SumNeuron https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sw1sh/560fc4c27d9f173bf85e34c88e327a7d/raw/d9ccc04d50ec00dc3e59cea9cabdd70845db15a3/t-SNE.nb

Comment: @swish, yes in traditional statistics, but they define variance as $sigma_i$: *where, $sigma_i$ is the variance*... so I figured that was just a weird terminology thing...

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev yes I already have the python code, the question is about implementing it in Mathematica, not necessarily with a naive translation, but from the equations and simple pseudo-code provided.

Comment: +1 just for the clarity of the question. I was looking for the pseudocode for this algorithm and you came on top on google :)

Comment: I cannot figure out how to use perplexity in Equation 1.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ in regards to what it is or how it is used? To the former perplexity is simply $2^H(P_i)$,  and can be interpreted as a smooth measure of the effective number of neighbors. If you are a visual learner, perhaps https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/ will be of use. If it is the later, the variance for the Gaussian centered on each high dimensional data point is chosen to match a fixed perplexity.

Answer (score 9):

In Mathematica 11.1 [`DimensionReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DimensionReduce.html) supports t-SNE.

[image]

Comment: Which implementation? The Barnes Hut? Or the traditional? Can one set the Perplexity? This would be important given that Perplexity basically defined the scope on which t-SNE searches for local structure in high dimensions.

Comment: @SumNeuron Good question. But I don't know.

Comment: @sumneuron You can set the perplexity like this `Method -> {"TSNE", "Perplexity" -> 100}`

Comment: @user5601 thanks! Just f.y.i. the original publication Perplexity was best set between 5-50 :)

Comment: @SumNeuron: we use the original exact-gradient method for very small datasets, and a parallelized C++ implementation of the Barnes-Hut approximation method for larger datasets.